# how to reduce wait time in perl

Tags: perl

I have script that queries a database a variable number of times per second.

For example, to achieve **36,000 queries per hour** we input **600 queries** per minute into our script.  **600 x  60 = 36,000**

This is the output we get you can see the delay between each query

```
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.313]
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.413]
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.513]
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.613]
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.713]
{1} [2019-11-06 21:38:01.813]
```

My problem is we are missing out on that 0.0100 because we have a wait time inplace.

rates per minute = varies we can change this to a max of 960 queries per min but we would want fourmla that is flexible for 0-960.

my $wait_time = (1 / $rpm) * 60 * 1(connection); (max of 4 connections) wait time increases based on number of connections

Does anyone know how to reduce the wait time in between queries ?

thanks

This is the code line

> my $wait_time = (1 / $rpm) * 60 * 1;

So when i enter in 600 queries per min

This code line calcuates the wait time based on number of connection we have

my $wait_time = (1 / 600) * 60 * 1;

1/600 * 60 * 1 = WAIT: 0.1

Comment: Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: Re "*Here is a example of the epoch time output.*", Times of what?

Comment: Re "*we are missing out on that 0.00100*", What does that mean? What's a 0.00100?

Comment: "_we have a wait time inplace_" -- what "wait time" ?  You are asking how to reduce "wait time" so presumably you haven't set it up  yourself  ...?

Comment: @ikegami -  Sorry about the mix up with  query - i have updated the post. The output is of the query run time - how long it took to perform it. The wait time is the difference between the 2 values e.g. 313-413 first line in the query.

Comment: Re "*The output is of the query run time - how long it took to perform it.*", It took 2019 years to perform?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your processing of the query needs time. A fragile solution, if i interpret your problem right, is to measure the time the current processing takes and substract that from the next sleep time. Of course that would break if the processing time equals or exceeds the sleep time.

A clean solution would be to have a dedicated main loop that does nothing but sleeping and firing off queries in separate threads.

Comment: Launching threads is pretty expensive. This would end up drifting if you sleep for `$wait_time`. That's the case even if launching threads wasn't that expensive. Doing something 36,000 times adds up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help because I have a very hard time understanding your question. I think you are concerned that you aren't making queries at the rate you desire.

It could be because you think of the wait time as being static. It's not the *wait time* that's static —that's dependent on how long the previous query took— it's the *interval* that's static.

```
use Time::HiRes qw( time sleep );  # Add support for fractional times.

my $interval = (1 / $qpm) * 60 * 1;  # In (fractional) seconds.
my $next_run = time;
while (1) {
   my $wait = $next_run - time;
   sleep($wait) if $wait > 0;
   $next_run += $interval;

   ... do work ...
}
```

Comment: Fixed bug. . . .